# Glua makeshift minimap script not working

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
local Frame = vgui.Create("DFrame")
Frame:SetPos(5, 5)
Frame:SetSize(16362.369140625 / 50 * 2, 16362.369140625 / 50 * 2)
Frame:SetTitle("Button")
Frame:SetVisible(true)
Frame:SetDraggable(true)
Frame:ShowCloseButton(true)
Frame:MakePopup()
local Button = vgui.Create("DButton", Frame)
Button:SetText("Test")
Button:SetPos(75 + (75 / 2), 60)
Button:SetSize(75, 37.5)
Button.DoClick = function() -- Everything above this works fine
    for i, v in ipairs(player.GetAll()) do
        rp = v:GetPos() --Raw Position
        print("X = ", tostring(rp.x)) -- debug
        print("Y = ", tostring(rp.y)) -- debug
        if tostring(rp.x) == "^-" then
            ppx = tonumber(tostring(rp.x):gsub("-", ""))
        else
            ppx = tonumber(tostring(rp.x)) * 2
        end
        if tostring(rp.y) == "^-" then
            ppy = tonumber(tostring(rp.y):gsub("-1", ""))
        else
            ppy = tonumber(tostring(rp.y)) * 2
        end
        local Button1 = vgui.Create("DButton", Frame)
        Button1:SetPos(ppx / 50, ppy / 50)
        Button1:SetSize(10, 10)
    end
end
```

I'm new to glua (and lua overall) so for my second project I wanted to make a minimap.

The issue is it doesn't convert negatives to positives and doesn't double the coords.
The gui starts from 0, it cannot go into negative, that is why I need to remove the negative symbol and why I need to double the positive coords.

As I said I am new so I would like a get a explanation for why this is broken, thank you.

Comment: You can convert negative numbers to positive with `math.abs(number)`. Overall, I don't recommend using `tostring` and `tonumber` too often... they will slow down your code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your `Button.DoClick` for you and tidied it up:

```lua
Button.DoClick = function() -- Everything above this works fine
    for i, v in ipairs(player.GetAll()) do

        rp = v:GetPos() --Raw Position

        print("X = ", rp.x) -- tip: you don't need tostring here
        print("Y = ", rp.y)

        -- check if less than 0 for negative numbers
        if rp.x < 0 then
            rp.x = -rp.x -- negative of a negative is positive
        else
            rp.x = rp.x * 2
        end

        -- do the same thing for y
        if rp.y < 0 then
            rp.y = -rp.y -- negative of a negative is positive
        else
            rp.y = rp.y * 2
        end

        local Button1 = vgui.Create("DButton", Frame)
        Button1:SetPos(rp.x / 50, rp.y / 50)
        Button1:SetSize(10, 10)
    end
end
```

As for why your old code didn't work, assuming `^-` was meant to be a lua pattern, string equality checks don't use patterns as far as I'm aware. They check strings against each other literally without any pattern parsing.

If really still want to use patterns and tostring, something like `if string.match( tostring(rp.x, "^-")` would get the job done, but I wouldn't recommend it since as @Mooshua pointed out it's going to make your code a lot slower than it needs to be. If you can, break out your math skills and avoid strings entirely—it'll save much headache going forward.

Comment: A friend of mine pointed out that both `-2` and `1` will map to `2` with this code, which seems unintended despite being what your post asked for.  Are you sure your logic is going to do what you intend for it to?